# How to create instances of a global javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, instance

I am a C++/Java developer that has been tasked with a javascript project and I cannot seem to figure this issue out.

I am working with a javascript file that defines a namespace by direct assignment as described [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/)

So here is my attempt at an overly simplified example namespace

```
// testns.js
var ns = { }
ns.val = -1;

ns.setVal = function(newVal) {
    this.val = newVal;
}
```

And here is what I would like to do

```
//myScript.js
function testNamespaceInstances()
{
    var nsInstance1 = ns;
    nsInstance1.setVal(1);

    var nsInstance2 = ns;
    nsInstance2.setVal(2);

    console.log("nsInstance1.val: " + nsInstance1.val);
    console.log("nsInstance2.val: " + nsInstance2.val);
}
```

That function will output

```
nsInstance1.val: 2
nsInstance2.val: 2
```

Is there anything I can do without modifying the testns.js file that the namespace is declared in so that the function will output

```
nsInstance1.val: 1
nsInstance2.val: 2
```

Edit: Added some more details to the example code.  I would also like to note I am attempting to simplify a more complex javascript file that I am working with

Answer (score 3):

Just create a second namespace (object, really): `nsInstance2 = {};` -- the problem here is that both `nsInstance1` and `nsInstance2` are pointing to the same object, so naturally, if you change the properties of one, it'll be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 3):

Complex data types in JavaScript are copied as references, so your `nsInstance1` and `nsInstance2` variables merely point to the namespace object - they do not copy or instantiate it.

To instantiate it, the namespace must be declared as a function, not an object literal, and referenced with the `new` keyword. Only functions can be used in instantiation in JavaScript.

```
function NS() {}
var ns1 = new NS();
var ns2 = new NS();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree that this is the way to go, unfortunately I am trying to accomplish this without modifying the contents of the nstest.js file.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, you're going to have to re-think things because object literals cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Utkanos, what about `Object.create`?

Comment: @katspaugh - sure, worth a mention, but I don't tend to suggest it as I assume OPs need support for IE <= 8.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are no namespaces in JavaScript. `{}` is just an object literal, the same as `new Object()`.

Second, you don't instantiate objects by giving them several references. You can instantiate an object with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/):

```
var nsInstance1 = Object.create(ns);
var nsInstance2 = Object.create(ns);
```

Comment: No namespaces in JavaScript?  ["Namespaces can be found in almost any serious JavaScript application."](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/#beginners)

Comment: @michaelok, whenever you have to type a dot before a symbol – it's not a namespace but a fake. We need portable scope, like `import * from module` in Python.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the explanation.  This [article](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/commonjs-effort-sets-javascript-on-path-for-world-domination/) and the [post](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/2009/01/29/what-server-side-javascript-needs/) by Kevin Dangoor also clarified the issue "JavaScript needs a standard way to include other modules and for those modules to live in discreet namespaces. There are easy ways to do namespaces, but there’s no standard programmatic way to load a module (once!)."

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
var ns = function() {
    return {};
};
```

and

```
function testNamespaceInstances() {
    var nsInstance1 = new ns;
    nsInstance1.val = 1;

    var nsInstance2 = new ns;
    nsInstance2.val = 2;

    console.log("nsInstance1.val: " + nsInstance1.val);
    console.log("nsInstance2.val: " + nsInstance2.val);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/W4rjN/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
//myScript.js
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (var i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};

function testNamespaceInstances()
{
    var nsInstance1 = ns.clone();
    nsInstance1.val = 1;

    var nsInstance2 = ns.clone();
    nsInstance2.val = 2;

    console.log("nsInstance1.val: " + nsInstance1.val);
    console.log("nsInstance2.val: " + nsInstance2.val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your are taking `ns` at a global scope, you can just directly assign values to it like-

`//testns.js`

```
var ns = { }
ns.val = -1;

function testNamespaceInstances()
{
    ns.val1=1;
    ns.val2=2;

    console.log("ns.val1: " + ns.val1);
    console.log("ns.val2: " + ns.val2);
}
```